# How to figure out the log of a number without a calculator?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, logarithms

I have seen people look at log (several digit number) and rattle off the first couple of digits.

I can get the value for small values (aka the popular or easy to know roots), but is there a formula.  Similar to how to tell if a number is divisible by an integer.

I have read [this](http://www.curiousmath.com/index.php?name=News&file=article&sid=32) and [this](http://www.curiousmath.com/index.php?name=News&file=article&sid=43) but could some one explain why it works?

Comment: To answer the _title_: Check the CRC Handbook or use a slide rule.

Comment: The first link is simply using the basic rules for logarithms - the log of a product is equal to the sum of the logs (working in base 10). As an example, take $log(3025) = log(3.025 \times 10^3)=log(3.025)+log(10^3) = log (3.025)+3 \approx 3.48$ (using that $log(3)$ is 0.48). The power of 10 was chosen because $log(3)$ was known.

Comment: Links are broken. Could you update them?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The idea of the first article is to rewrite any positive number $x$ as :
$$\tag{1}x=m\cdot 10^{\,e}$$ with $m$ the 'mantissa' : a real number between $1$ and $10$ (excluded)
and $\,e\,$ the 'exponent' (or "power of ten") which is a signed integer.

From this we have $\;\tag{2}\log_{10}(x)= e+\log_{10}(m)$

(to keep notations short I'll write $\,\log(x)\,$ for $\,\log_{10}(x)\,$ and use $\,\ln(x)$ for the 'natural' logarithm)

Since the mantissa is between $1$ and $10$ the idea is to memorize the first logarithms (here I'll use up to $5$ digits, you may use fewer or more digits if you prefer) :

$$
\begin{array} {ll}
m & \log\,m\\
1 & 0\\
2 & 0.30103\\
3 & 0.47712\\
4 & 0.60206\\
5 & 0.69897\\
6 & 0.77815\\
7 & 0.84510\\
8 & 0.90309\\
9 & 0.95424\\
\end{array}
$$

This seems to be much work but these values (except $\log(7)$) are not independent :

- $\log(2^n)=n\,\log(2)\;$ so that $\;\log(4)=2\log(2),\;\log(8)=3\log(2),\cdots$
- more generally $\;\log(a\cdot b)=\log(a)+\log(b)\;$ so that the table could be rewritten (using $\,1=\log(10)=\log(2)+\log(5)$) :

$$
\begin{array} {lll}
m & \log\,m\\
1 & 0\\
2 & 0.30103 &\log(2)\\
3 & 0.47712 &\log(3)\\
4 & 0.60206 &2\,\log(2)\\
5 & 0.69897 &1-\log(2)\\
6 & 0.77815 &\log(2)+\log(3)\\
7 & 0.84510 &\log(7)\\
8 & 0.90309 &3\,\log(2)\\
9 & 0.95424 &2\,\log(3)\\
\end{array}
$$

The table may thus be rebuilt with just three values (two if $\,\log(7)\,$ is omitted)!

One should memorize too $\;\ln(10) \approx 2.3026\,$ and its multiplicative inverse $\;\dfrac{1}{\ln(10)}=\dfrac{\ln(e)}{\ln(10)}=\log(e)\approx \dfrac 1{2.3026}\approx 0.4343$.

The classical expansion $\;\ln(1+x)\approx x\;$ will be rewritten as :
$$\tag{3}\log(1+x)=\frac{\ln(1+x)}{\ln(10)}\approx 0.4343\cdot x$$ 
(with $x$ replaced by $\;x-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^3}3-\cdots\,$ if needed)

Let's apply all this to recover the (unfortunately lost...) value of $\,\log(7)\,$ using only $\;\log(2),\log(3),\log(e)$. One method is to use $\;\log(7)=\dfrac{\log(7^2)}2\;$ and :

\begin{align}
\log(49)&=\log\left(50\;\left(1-\frac 1{50}\right)\right)\\
&=\log\left(\frac{100}2\right)+\log\left(1-\frac 1{50}\right)\\
&\approx\log(100)-\log(2)-0.4343\left(\frac 1{50}+\frac 1{2\cdot50^2}\right)\\
&\approx 2-\log(2)-\frac{0.8686}{100}\left(1+\frac 1{100}\right)\\
&\approx 2-0.30103-0.00877\\
&\approx 1.69020
\end{align}

Dividing by $2$ will indeed give the wished $0.84510$. Without the $\dfrac{x^2}2$ term we would get $\,0.84514$ : also not that bad!
$$-$$

Let's further practice and compute $\log(29012)$ as in your article : $\log(29012)=\log(2.9012\cdot 10^4)=4+\log(2.9012)$

In first approximation we have $\;\log(2.9012) \approx \log(3) \approx 0.477\;$ and deduce that $\log(29012)\approx 4+0.477 \approx 4.477$.

we have $\;2.9012\approx 3\cdot 0.9671 \approx 3\cdot (1-0.0329)\;$ so that 
\begin{align}
\log(2.9012)&\approx \log(3)+\log(1-0.0329)\\
&\approx 0.47712-0.434\cdot 0.033\\
&\approx 0.47712-0.0143\\
&\approx 0.4628
\end{align}

and we got $\;\log(29012)\approx 4.4628\,$ not so far from the exact $4.4625776\cdots$

It is important to understand that the table of logarithms allows too the reverse computation that is to compute $10^{\,x}$.

Of course $10^{\,\log(2)}=2$ so that for example $10^{\,0.3}$ will be just a bit smaller than $2$.

For additional precision and for $x\ll 1$ let's write the useful $\displaystyle 10^x=e^{x\ln(10)}\approx 1+\ln(10)x\;$ or 
$$\tag{4}10^{\,x}\approx 1+2.3026\cdot x$$

To compute $10^{\,x}$ decompose $x$ in its integer part $i$ and fractional part $f$
then $10^{\,i+f}=10^{\,i}\cdot 10^{\,f}$ : the mantissa of this result $10^{\,f}$ will be found using the table and $i$ will of course be the exponent.

After that all applications may follow : compute $a^b$ for any positive real $a$ and real $b$ using $\,\log(a^b)=b\,\log(a)\;$ so that
$$a^b=10^{\,b\log(a)}$$

Computing the $n$-th root of a positive real number will just be the special case  $\;b=\dfrac 1n$.

Example $\sqrt[5]{1212}$ : 
\begin{align} 
1212&\approx 3\cdot 4\cdot 100\cdot 1.01\\
\log(1212)&\approx 2+\log(3)+\log(4)+0.4343/100\\
\dfrac{\log(1212)}{5}&\approx \frac{2+0.47712+0.60206+0.00434}5\\
\approx 0.6167
\end{align}
The answer (approximatively $10^{\,0.6167}$) will thus be a little over $4$.

More exactly $\,0.61670=0.60206+0.01464\,$ and since $\,10^{0.01464}\approx 1+2.3\cdot 0.0146 \approx 1.0336\;$ an approximate result will be  $4\cdot 1.0336$ that is : $$\sqrt[5]{1212}\approx 4.134$$ while the exact result is $4.1371429\cdots$.

Many methods may be used to get more precision :

- from $1212=1200\cdot 1.01$ expand the logarithm (and/or the power of $10$) to second order as done for $\log(7)$
- compose (+ -) different exact values of logarithms to get values near the searched one (example $\,1.33\approx \dfrac 43$ and thus $\;\log(1.33)\approx \log(4)-\log(3)$)
- memorize values nearer to $1$ : $\log(1.1)\approx 0.041393,\ \log(1.2)=\log(\frac{3\cdot4}{10})\approx 0.07918$ and so on (you should nearly 'recognize' $\log(1.01)= 0.004321$... (see $\log(e)$) and won't need to memorize $\log(1.001)$)
- $\cdots$

Wishing you much fun discovering yourself other tricks,

Comment: thanks, this is a great answer.

Comment: @MaoYiyi: Thanks for that, you are welcome!

Comment: can i mail Raymond Manzoni in person. i am new here, and i have 1 reputition. i however need help

Comment: There was a suggested edit of this answer by this user: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/30581/oluwatola-imoleayo, which I rejected.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Aryabhata !

Comment: @oluwatolaimoleayo You should use the button at the top-right "Ask question" to get mathematical help here (or perhaps edit your question if the subject is logarithms)! Concerning my email see this [thread](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=7047633)

Comment: Good explanation, but there's an easier way of doing it.  This is extremely complicated, plus you use approximation which is lacking precision.

Comment: @annoying_squid: Well I know other methods but chose to present this one here (retrospectively I think I shouldn't have added the evaluation of $\log(7)$ to second order but else I am rather satisfied by this answer). Of course you are encouraged to present your own easier method here or in a more recent thread like this [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1793127/calculating-logs-and-fractional-exponents-by-hand?lq=1) !

Answer (score 8):

One can get very good approximations by using

$$\frac 1 2 \log  \left|\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right| =x+\frac {x^3} 3+ \frac {x^5}5+\cdots$$

Say you want to get $\log 3$. Then take $x=1/2$. Then you get

$$\log 3 \approx 2\left( \frac 1 2 +\frac 1 {24} + \frac 1 {140} \right)=1.0976190\dots$$

The real value is $\log 3 = 1.098612289\dots$

Take another term to get

$\log 3 \approx 1.098065476\dots$.

Note that this particular series has the advantage that for $x < 1$ (which is where it works) you get "exponentially increasing" approximations.

Comment: One can get slightly more bang for the buck with Padé approximants. As already shown by Peter, using the $\mathrm{artanh}$ series is a great idea (due to the oddness of $\mathrm{artanh}$), but comparing $$x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}+\frac{x^7}{7}$$ and $$\frac{x-\frac{11 x^3}{21}}{1-\frac{6 x^2}{7}+\frac{3 x^4}{35}}$$ for $x=1/2$, the Padé approximant has a slight edge over the series...

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by recourse to Taylor series. For $\ln(x)$ centered at 1, i.e. where $0 < x \leq 2$:
$$
\ln(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(x-1)^n}{n}= (x-1) - \frac{1}{2}(x-1)^2 + \frac{1}{3}(x-1)^3 + \frac{1}{4}(x-1)^4 + \cdots 
$$

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a pretty miserable way to do calculations, except in the situation where you have a number that is close enough to 1 that you only need 1 or 2 terms.

Comment: The related series $\ln x = \ln a + \frac{x-a}{a} - \frac{(x-a)^2}{2a^2} + \ldots$ for $0<x\leq 2a$ is also not very useful in this regard.

Comment: @oenamen and you too, Kaleb. Thanks for those equations.  Always good to build up one's equation notebook.

Comment: @MaoYiyi: Glad to help. To see how bad this approach is try approximating $\log_{10} 3025$. It's only useful if $(x-a)/a$ is small.

Comment: @oenamen Yes, I got that after trying a few. Just wanted to know how they did it. Don't worry, I'll still use my ti

Answer (score 1):

A curve can be approximated with line segments.

If $4 \le x \lt 5$, then $\log(x) \approx 0.1(x+2)$.  For example, $\log(4.1) \approx 0.61$, $\log(4.2) \approx 0.62$, $\log(4.3) \approx 0.63, \ldots, \log(4.9) \approx 0.69$.

If $7 \le x \lt 10$, then $\log(x) \approx 0.1(x/2 + 5)$.  For example, $\log(7.2) \approx 0.1(7.2/2 + 5) \approx 0.86$.