# How to compute exponents?

Tags: logarithms

I read [How to figure out the log of a number without a calculator?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135368/how-to-figure-out-the-log-of-a-number-without-a-calculator#135392)
but what is actually used to compute the basic tables themselves, 
Newton's method or Taylor series?

1. If Taylor series is used then how is it done?
2. Does a calculator use the Taylor series? Is it fast and the recommended way over Newton's method?

Comment: They use an algorithm called CORDIC that involves bitshifting.  Here is a link:  http://www.qc.cuny.edu/Academics/Degrees/DMNS/Faculty%20Documents/Sultan1.pdf

Comment: i didnt ask about trignometry, i asked for logarithms which is much simpler, so do they use newtons method or taylor serious

Comment: It would be nice if you would show some example rather than just give a link. The taylor series is helpful : $\ln(x+1)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$

Comment: Which kind of logarithm is to figure out ? $\log_{10}$ ot $\ln$ ?

Comment: Calculators usually use taylor series for $\sin$ , $\cos$ , $\exp$ , etc.

Comment: @reori: ncmathsadist is quite right. CORDIC is not limited to trigonometry.

Comment: Newton's method isn't used to compute logarithms. Because that would mean solving an equation such as $x-e^y=0$, requiring to evaluate exponentials for several iterates, which would be unacceptably inefficient. For direct evaluation, least-squares or least-deviation polynomials can be preferred over Taylor.