# How to approximate rational exponents?

Tags: irrational-numbers, computational-mathematics

On a recent exam, in an integer-type question in Chemistry, I calculated my final answer to be 10^0.6, I thought I had calculated the answer incorrectly as there was no way that would be the answer. I just left it since there were no calculators allowed.
Turns out, putting it into a calculator later, it's about 3.99 or 4 (That was the answer).
I asked my Maths teacher but he didn't have a way (Except memorizing the anti-log table), How do you go about estimating numbers like these?

Comment: Not sure what an "integer-type" question is.  Do you mean to say that you know in advance that the answer is an integer?  If so, then note that $10^{.6}>\sqrt {10}>3$  and $10^{3/5}<5 \iff 10^3<5^5$ and the latter is easily checked.

Comment: A short table of anti-log or log may indeed help... In this case $\log_{10}(2)\approx 0.3$ (or [better](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135368/how-to-figure-out-the-log-of-a-number-without-a-calculator) $0.30103$) so that it is nearly $2*2$

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Manzoni Ahh I see... I did know the log of 0.3 but I didn't think of it that way. That's quite useful and the best one I've found!

Comment: @lulu Yes, an integer-type question does mean that the answer would be an integer. Thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 4):

There is no general recipe for doing it in your head. But in this case you want
$$
10^{0.6}=10^{3/5}=(10^3)^{1/5}=\sqrt[5]{1000}.
$$
Since $4^5=1024$, the number $10^{0.6}$ is very slightly below $4$.